# BeanIO - "Too few fields, expected 8 minimum", why?

Tags: java, parsing, text-parsing, bean-io

I'm using BeanIO 1.2 in java and here's my mapping:

```
  <stream name="RecordImport" format="delimited">
    <record name="Record" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" class="com.myclasses.Record">
      <field name="date" type="date" format="MM/dd/yyyy" trim="true"/>
      <field name="user" type="string" trim="true"/>
      <field name="storage" type="string" trim="true"/>
      <field name="product" type="string" trim="true"/>
      <field name="qty" type="bigdecimal" format="#,##0" trim="true"/>
      <field name="altQty1" type="bigdecimal" format="#,##0" trim="true"/>
      <field name="altQty2" type="bigdecimal" format="#,##0" trim="true"/>
      <field name="altQty3" type="bigdecimal" format="#,##0" trim="true"/>
    </record>
  </stream>
```

and my text file looks like this:

```
3/11/2012   lpq 200011  RDD1006 8           
3/11/2012   lpq 200011  RDD1006 8           
3/11/2012   lpq 200011  RDD1006 8   1   2   3
3/11/2012   lpq 200011  RDD1006 8
```

The result is that I get this message:

```
"- Line 4: Too few fields, expected 8 minimum."
```

Now this is strange because I do have the tabs in place to indicate there are 8 fields on the fourth line. This seems to happen due to the fact that the last tree fields in the 4th line are null. I need the ability for them to be null and yet for this message not to be raised. What's also strange is that this happens only for the 4th line and not for 1st or 2nd.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try adding `minOccurs="0"` to your optional `<field>` declarations? See also: http://www.beanio.org/2.0/docs/reference/index.html#NullFields

Comment: Do you have to use tabs ? Can you use commas in your file ? That would be more explicit

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz When I added minOccurs="0" to my optional fields I got this exception: "minOccurs must be 1, or the field collection type must be set."

Comment: Does anybody have any other ideas?

Comment: does line 4 have a record terminator?

Answer (score 0):

I could not recreate the issue you're seeing (using BeanIO 1.2.5) without removing one of the trailing fields/tabs.  If they are indeed optional, you can set minLength="5" on the record definition.  BeanIO 2.x is a little more flexible and will allow you to set minOccurs="0" on trailing optional fields instead...

Good luck!